# How to test/mock AsyncTaskLoader with robotium and junit?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robotium, asynctaskloader

I use Robotium library and base JUnit framework for my test project. How can I test/mock AsyncTaskLoader? My AsyncTaskLoader initialize in onCreate method and when I call getActivity in my test it initialize and get data from web server or database. I don't wont AsyncTaskLoader load data.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't wont AsyncTaskLoader load data"?

Comment: I don't want that AsyncTaskLoader load data in my test. I want that it emulate mock data.